# ISO C, sprintf and decimal conversion grouped with thousands

Tags: c, iso

I'm trying to do a simple `sprintf` like this:

```
snprintf(dest, maxlen_dest, "%'lu", along);
```

Note the quote: **`'`** in the string.

This means (according to the manual):

> ' For decimal conversion (i, d, u, f, F, g, G) the output is to be
>   grouped with  thousands’  grouping  characters  if  the  locale
>   information indicates any.  Note that many versions of gcc(1) cannot
>   parse this option and will issue a warning.  SUSv2 does not include
>   %'F.

So when I compile, I get this warning:

```
../common/utils.c:29: warning: ISO C does not support the ''' printf flag
../common/utils.c:29: warning: ISO C does not support the ''' printf flag
```

So, my question is: is there a function that "supports the ''' printf flag" I could use?

I want my output to be like:

```
51 254 234
 1 424 000
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

Here's my Makefile (in case there's some options I should modify):

```
CC = gcc 
# -g = all debug options
CFLAGS = -g -I../common -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
OBJECTS = o/main.o o/opts.o o/verif_liens_bidirectionnels.o o/ecriture.o o/plugin_utils.o o/plugin_algo_groupes.o ../common/o/cell.o ../common/o/utils.o ../common/o/verif.o ../common/o/lecture.o

gen : $(OBJECTS)
  $(CC) -o gen $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -lm -lgd -lz

o/main.o : main.c
  $(CC) -o $@ -c main.c $(CFLAGS)

o/opts.o : opts.c opts.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c opts.c $(CFLAGS)

o/verif_liens_bidirectionnels.o : verif_liens_bidirectionnels.c verif_liens_bidirectionnels.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c verif_liens_bidirectionnels.c $(CFLAGS)

o/ecriture.o : ecriture.c ecriture.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c ecriture.c $(CFLAGS)

o/plugin_utils.o : plugin_utils.c plugin_utils.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c plugin_utils.c $(CFLAGS)

o/plugin_algo_groupes.o : plugin_algo_groupes.c plugin_algo_groupes.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c plugin_algo_groupes.c $(CFLAGS)

../common/o/cell.o : ../common/cell.c ../common/cell.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c ../common/cell.c $(CFLAGS)

../common/o/utils.o : ../common/utils.c ../common/utils.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c ../common/utils.c $(CFLAGS)

../common/o/verif.o : ../common/verif.c ../common/verif.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c ../common/verif.c $(CFLAGS)

../common/o/lecture.o : ../common/lecture.c ../common/lecture.h
  $(CC) -o $@ -c ../common/lecture.c $(CFLAGS)

clean :
  rm $(OBJECTS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add

```
../common/o/utils.o : CFLAGS := $(filter-out -pedantic,$(CFLAGS))
```

to the makefile, which should suppress the warning for the specific file.

If you don't want to rely on non-standard libc extensions, you'll have to implement the functionality yourself...

Comment: may I ask you to tell me exactly what to change in the Makefile? I've tried something like `o/plugin_utils.o : plugin_utils.c plugin_utils.h CFLAGS = $(filter-out -pedantic,$(CFLAGS))` but it didn't work

Comment: @Oliver: just paste the line above verbatim into the makefile, eg just before the actual rule (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific ); do not change the `:=` to `=` (you want a simply expanded variable as you reference the same variable in its definition), do not try joining the rules...